# How to call a .NET 6 library (C#) from unmanaged code

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, unmanaged

I've been calling a C# (.NET Framework 4.61) library from MetaTrader 4 (unmanaged code) using UnmanagedCode (RGiesecke.DllExport), but I'd like to create a new project in .NET 6. Is there an alternative NuGet package available made for .NET 6 as UnmanagedCode hasn't been updated since 2015, and VS 2022 keeps whining at me.

Example:

```
using RGiesecke.DllExport; 
namespace HGTrader { 
   public static class HGTrader { 
      [DllExport("DoTradingCalculations", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)] 
      public static int DoTradingCalculations(double ask, double bid, double balance, double equity) 
       { 
          //return tradeEngine.ChangeList.Count; 
          return 0; 
       } 
   } 
}
```

> VS 2022 won't compile: Warning NU1701 Package 'UnmanagedExports 1.2.7'
> was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1,
> .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7,
> .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2,
> .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework
> 'net6.0-windows7.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with
> your project.

Comment: Can you share (a [mre], something that works with 4.61 and keeps whining in 6) of the unamanaged code? and add it tp the question using [edit] ?

Comment: I am no expert on this, but this seems to be a good replacement: https://github.com/dkxce/DllExport

Comment: @Luuk That source you linked is an example of Robert Giesecke UnmanagedExport library. I’ve tested his latest repack and upgrade and they only seem to work on .Net Framework and .Net Standard.  On .NET 5.0 or 6.0 the dlls will compile and will show as exported when using dumpbin. The library will load in C++ and you can find a pointer to the function, but trying to execute it will get an exception. The same goes for 3F/DlllExport. I’d like to hear solutions for 5.0 and 6.0 as well.